# Pandas: Maintain a column after aggregation

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data look like as below:

[image]

The code used to build it is as follows:

```
  Data = pd.DataFrame({'Customer_ID':[1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5],
                 'Product_ID':['A','D','C','A','E','B','D','C','B','E'],
                 'SalesAmount':[12.34,13.55,34.00, 19.15,13.22,12.34,13.55,34.00, 19.15,13.22],
                     'ProductCost' : [12.34,13.55,34.00, 19.15,13.22,12.34,13.55,34.00, 19.15,13.22]})
```

My question is, how would I maintain a column after aggregation of columns needed ?

In my case I want to have the column Product_ID in the data after aggregation. The code and the result I used to aggregate  are as follows:

```
 Data_aggr = Data.groupby('Customer_ID').agg({'SalesAmount':[min,sum],
                                         'ProductCost':['mean',max] },'Product_ID')

 Data_aggr.columns = ["_".join(x) for x in Data_aggr.columns.ravel()]

 Data_aggr.index.name='Customer_ID'

 Data_aggr.reset_index(inplace=True)
 Data_aggr
```

Result:

[image]

My desired output is :

[image]

Comment: Please show your desired output (not just describe). `Data.groupby(['Customer_ID', 'Product_ID']).agg....` seems to work fine, but I can't tell if this is what you want.

Comment: I edited my question above. I tried the way you said, but giving me an error ; ValueError: No axis named Product_ID for object type <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

Comment: That's because you misspelled `Prodcuct_ID` in your input... should be `Product_ID`.

Comment: Can you describe your logic? How do you determine "A" for the first row. Is it just the first letter in your group?

Comment: Still giving me the same error!

Comment: No axis named ... is probably because you didn't pass a list as described: `.groupby(['Customer_ID', 'Product_ID'])`. Can you check the brackets?

Comment: I guess you forget `[]` in `Data.groupby(['Customer_ID', 'Product_ID'])`

Comment: The output is a edited picture to show you how it would look like. I was looking for a column that was group by product_ID along with Customer_ID

Comment: Oh, yes! That worked. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need aggregate all necessary columns, e.g. by `first`:

```
Data_aggr = Data.groupby('Customer_ID').agg({'SalesAmount':[min,sum],
                                         'ProductCost':['mean',max],'Product_ID':'first' })

Data_aggr.columns = ["_".join(x) for x in Data_aggr.columns.ravel()]

Data_aggr = Data_aggr.rename(columns={'Product_ID_first':'Product_ID'}).reset_index()
print (Data_aggr)
   Customer_ID  SalesAmount_min  SalesAmount_sum  ProductCost_mean  \
0            1            12.34            24.68             12.34   
1            2            13.55            27.10             13.55   
2            3            34.00            68.00             34.00   
3            4            19.15            38.30             19.15   
4            5            13.22            26.44             13.22   

   ProductCost_max Product_ID  
0            12.34          A  
1            13.55          D  
2            34.00          C  
3            19.15          A  
4            13.22          E
```

Or grouping by multiple columns, but output is different:

```
Data_aggr = Data.groupby(['Customer_ID','Product_ID']).agg({'SalesAmount':[min,sum],
                                         'ProductCost':['mean',max]})

Data_aggr.columns = ["_".join(x) for x in Data_aggr.columns.ravel()]

Data_aggr = Data_aggr.reset_index()
print (Data_aggr)
   Customer_ID Product_ID  SalesAmount_min  SalesAmount_sum  ProductCost_mean  \
0            1          A            12.34            12.34             12.34   
1            1          B            12.34            12.34             12.34   
2            2          D            13.55            27.10             13.55   
3            3          C            34.00            68.00             34.00   
4            4          A            19.15            19.15             19.15   
5            4          B            19.15            19.15             19.15   
6            5          E            13.22            26.44             13.22   

   ProductCost_max  
0            12.34  
1            12.34  
2            13.55  
3            34.00  
4            19.15  
5            19.15  
6            13.22
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am not really looking for values in the column as shown in the picture. The picture is edited to show my desired output.  I was looking for a column that was group by product_ID along with Customer_ID.

Comment: @L.G. - First solution is like need in picture, second is like jpp suggest, but output is different.

Comment: @L.G. - Output is different, because if use multiple columns in groupby like `Data.groupby(['Customer_ID','Product_ID'])` it grouping by combinations of specified columns, so this output is expected.

Comment: @jezreal Got the answer. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: @L.G. - OK, answer is different like me 2 solutions?